# jQuery live, change in not working in IE6, IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The code below works as expected in FF but not in IEs...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.facet_dropdown select').live('change', function() {
        var changed_facet = $(this).attr('id');
        var facets = $('select', $(this).closest('form'));
        var args = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?ajax=1';
        var clear = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < facets.length; i++) {
            var ob = $(facets[i]);
            var val = ob.val();
            if(clear) {
                val = '';
            }
            args += '&' + ob.attr('id') + '=' + val;
            if(ob.attr('id') == changed_facet) {
                clear = true;
            }
        }

        $.getJSON(args, function(json) {
            for(widget_id in json) {
                var sel = '#field-' + widget_id + ' div.widget';
                $(sel).html(json[widget_id]);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Have you attempted to deduce what is causing the problem at least?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$.live()` does not support the `change` event:

> **Currently not supported**: blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit
>   http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Try using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) instead?

Comment: Ran into this exact problem and even read the docs and missed the non-supporting-ness.

Comment: Just wanted to post an update to this. First, I noticed the URL you posted is now redirecting to http://api.jquery.com/live/ . Second, the passage you quoted regarding change event being "currently not supported" is no longer found on this page, as it seems like I.E. support now works in jquery 1.4.2.  I had just come across this same problem on a page using 1.3.2, upgraded it to 1.4.2, and it's now working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note: jQuery 1.4 now supports the live function for all normal events.  It didn't work with IE8 until recently, but I believe this is fixed with jQuery 1.4.2.  See this resolved jQuery ticket: [IE8 DOES NOT SUPPORT THE CHANGE EVENT WHILE USING LIVE](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5851)

Comment: Sorry, voting down this answer because the question mentioned IE6 and IE7 (not IE8) and it still doesn't work in IE6 with jQuery 1.4.2 because IE6 doesn't bubble the change event. Just to avoid people thinking this is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I used -

```
jQuery('#id').find('select').live("click", function(){
  jQuery(this).change(function(){
    //your code
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `delegate()` function instead `live()`. It the same as live, but supports more events and works fine in IE. In yout case it will be

```
$('div.facet_dropdown select').delegate('change', function() { ... });
```

and correspondent undelegate() function

Answer (score 2):

Also note that as of jQuery 1.7 you should use "on" instead of delegate or live.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Live suffers from a bunch more problems than just the old "no change event" issue: http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn