# Using argument (this) passed via element eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, element, arguments

I want to use the argument I pass (this) in a JS function and treat it as an jQuery variable.
Example:

```
<script>    
function useMe(obj){
  $(obj).val();
  ...
  ... 
  ...
}
</script>


<select id="selectid" onChange="useMe(this)">
    <option>......</option>
</select>
```

Is there a possibility to treat the passed argument as a jQuery element?

Btw. I need to do it this way, because the select-element isn't created on load. The select element will be created later asynchronously.

So, this won't work:

```
$("select").each(function (i){
    var select_id = $(this).attr("id");                
    $(this).change(function(e){
```

because it doesn't exist yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use your jQuery solution, you would just need to run the script after the ajax call for the select is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your element isn't created on load, and loaded asynchronously instead you can bind the change event like this:

```
$('select').live('change',function(){
  // ...
});
```

This will bind the defined function to the change event on every existing and on every new select item.

**Update**: You need at least jQuery 1.4.1 for this

Comment: does it work for IE6?

UPDATE:
found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451760/jquery-live-change-in-not-working-in-ie6-ie7

Answer (score 0):

If the element doesn't exist at the document load it means that it is later added maybe by an AJAX call. If this is the case just put the `change` handle registration in the `success` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somescript',
    success: function() {
        // some code that injects the select into the DOM
        // ...
        $("select").each(function(i) {
            var select_id = $(this).attr("id");                
            $(this).change(function(e) {
                // ...
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: cool thanks. I still got one question. Where do i need to insert this code? Into the file which loads the file or into the loaded (ajax) file?

Comment: you should already have this code somewhere. the only code you need to insert is `$("select) ...` within the function called on success

Answer (score 0):

If you do choose to stick with your `onchange` attribute (which I would advise against), just use:

```
<script>    
function useMe($obj){
  $obj.val();
  ...
  ... 
  ...
}
</script>

<select id="selectid" onChange="useMe($(this))">
    <option>......</option>
</select>
```